# How to detect when I move from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I detect when moving from one activity to another using

```
Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY
```

?

I tried to use `Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY` to detect when the user is moving from one activity to another but I don't succeed. 
In fact, I detect when the user clicks on the Home button, but for the button Back, I don’t know how I can detect it.

I use this code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
RMConfig.CONTEXT.registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement a jar which is added to project, so I'm obliged to detect the activities from outside the application's code

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
```

for more info, check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowAttributesChanged%28android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams%29)

Comment: no, from project that will be exported to jar file , I can't add   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

Comment: @SabrineMoumni srry, didn't saw your comment (on your own post)